# Got "fatal: no tag message?" error when set git core.editor to "emacsclient -nc"

Tags: emacsclient, git

When I set the core.editor="emacsclient -nc", after I press "C-c C-c" in the  `.git/TAG_EDITMSG` buffer, I got the error message:

```
fatal: no tag message?
```

But here is the content of `.git/TAG_EDITMSG` file

```
test

#
# Write a message for tag:
#   v0.0.5
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored.
```

I have tried to set core.editor to `emacs` or `gedit -s`, they all work fine. TAGS are created.

Emacs: compiled from git commit "ecb069e"
Git  : 2.6.2
OS   : Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `-n` flag.  Git expects the editor to block and `-n` tells Emacs not to block.  Hence git tries to use the tag message before you even had the chance to write anything.